# Making SizeToContent take Title into account

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, title, sizetocontent

Here's the XAML code for a very simple WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="TitleTester.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Long, verbose, unabridged title" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Label>Short text</Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I open this window, the text `Short text` is displayed in full; however, the title bar only displays `L...` (the first letter of `Long, verbose, unabridged title`). I would like the opened window to be wide enough to display the full title, and no wider. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set WPF Window's width equal to the content in its Title Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839479/how-to-set-wpf-windows-width-equal-to-the-content-in-its-title-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread should help you solve your issue : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/b9ea5bf1-04f2-47c9-bf7c-a2a804e105a4