# How to set WPF Window's width equal to the content in its Title Bar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

If I have Window in WPF as follows:

```
<Window
    Title="Alter Window Width so that the complete title is shown."
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
```

This window will automatically resize to make sure all of its content is visible. But it doesn't do the same for the title, so it's possible that a part of the title will be hidden when the window is shown.

What can be done to make sure that the width of the window is enough to show the title in the title bar?

Comment: Is your `Title` dynamic? If not, why not just assign a `MinWidth` to the window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a hidden textblock in to the window:

```
<TextBlock 
   Text="{Binding Path=Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" 
   Visibility="Hidden" 
   Height="0" 
   Margin="100 0 0 0">
</TextBlock>
```

The Margin allows for the windows controls to be pushed out of the way.

The Height makes the control take up no vertical space.

The Visiblity is probable not required because of the zero height, but by setting it to hidden will cause it to take up space on the canvas but show nothing.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but This still doesn't show up the complete title. 20% of it still reamins hidden. This is because Title bar contains other things as well besides title text viz. minimize, maximize buttons etc.

Comment: increase the margin value of 100 to cater for it, or turn them off on the window