# how to make NoResize WPF window that is sized to it's content but wide enough to show title entirely?

Tags: c#, wpf

Edit: I voted to close this myself cause there is exact duplicate (see comments).

I made window but the title is so long that it's shortened with ellipses. How to tell that i want the title to be always shown entirely?

```
<Window x:Class="xpower_wpf.StartupDialogs.AppSelectionWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ui="http://schemas.mycompany.com/fusion"
    Title="{StaticResource MyAppStrDlgSelectApplication}"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Applications}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApplication}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <!-- grid row for separator and for buttons -->
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you set `SizeToContent` to just "Height" and then calculate the width from the maximum of the content and title widths?

Comment: I struggled a lot with this problem, I have not found a clean solution yet. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839479/how-to-set-wpf-windows-width-equal-to-the-content-in-its-title-bar) if it helps you. Also with some search you will find a lot possible duplicates.

Comment: oops. exact duplicate :o