# How to make the text length of the title of a WPF Window greater 255 characters?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Created WPF application in VS2015. Set the Window's title to a string of length 290.

`Title = "123456789 223456789 323456789 423456789 523456789 623456789 723456789 823456789 923456789 133456789 233456789 333456789 433456789 533456789 633456789 733456789 833456789 933456789 143456789 243456789 343456789 443456789 543456789 643456789 743456789 843456789 943456789 153456789 253456789 ";`

When the application is run, the title is truncated to 255 characters (maximised window and window extended across 2 screens).

[image: Stretched Window]

1. How to increase the number of displayed characters?
2. What is the maximum allowed length for a WPF Window title?

I tried

- [How to set WPF Window's width equal to the content in its Title Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839479/how-to-set-wpf-windows-width-equal-to-the-content-in-its-title-bar)
- Setting title bar text in code and in XAML.

Comment: Good question. However why would you do that? Looks like you want to do some Inter process Communication over the window title...

Comment: In the application the title displays, a name + surname + reference number + telephone number. When the surname is long, the telephone number gets truncated. The user wants to see the telephone number.

Comment: 255/4 = 63 What's the name of the customer?

Comment: Don't know. I just got assigned the bug :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that 255 chars is an internal limitation in the `DefWindowProc()` native window function.

WPF changes the windows's title using a call to a native method:

```
UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowText(new HandleRef(this, CriticalHandle), title);
```

This method accepts strings of any length, so that should actually work. This is not a WPF problem.

But...

Even if you create a standard and native Win32 window that uses the `DefWindowProc()` function, you will observe the same behavior - maximum 255 characters in the window title.

Windows paints the title bar in response to a `WM_NCPAINT` message (along with the window frames, the system button, and so on). Inside the `DefWindowProc()` code that handles `WM_NCPAINT` messages, the code calls `GetWindowText()` to get the window's title string. In this call to `GetWindowText()`, the size of the buffer seems to be 255 **chars** (in old Windows, the buffer was only 79 **bytes**). This limits the length of a window's title to 255 characters.