# Increase Title Bar Text Limit

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a title bar with text that is being updated in certain places. This all works just fine, but occasionally we get a string that is too long, and gets cut off.

[image]

That should keep going for quite a while, as there is plenty of space, and is (for test purposes) being set for about 320 characters

```
For num As Integer = 0 To 150
    Me.ParentForm.Text &= num.ToString()
Next
```

I have been unable to find any property that limits this, or a way to change it so it will show everything I need it to show. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe not use the Title Bar as a data element.  There's no reason to do that.

Comment: @LarsTech Sure, but the application was written and placed into production years before I got here. Nothing for it now but to deal with it.

Comment: See [How to make the text length of the title of a WPF Window greater 255 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40548299/719186).  Ignore the WPF part.

Comment: @LarsTech Good find, and thank you. In my case, it does not get to 255 (cuts off about about 155), but it also an MDI form with some other odd things going on. In any case, it is enough for me to say we cannot do the requested change.